# Drupal 7.17 - Do I have to remove these files after installation?

Tags: drupal-7, installation

A site I'm currently managing has Drupal 7.17 on it.  I'm noticing the following files in the root of the website:

```
install.php
CHANGELOG.txt
INSTALL.txt
INSTALL.mysql.txt
INSTALL.pgsql.txt
LICENSE.txt
MAINTAINERS.txt
UPGRADE.txt
```

Researching this, tells me that as of Drupal 7.16, they fixed a security issue that would allow arbitrary code to run in install.php that would allow the re-installation of Drupal that someone could run.  But basically, I am wondering if any of these files (if left in the server root) could cause problems in Drupal 7.17?  Do I have to remove these files for security reasons?  Or is this no longer a security risk whatsoever in Drupal 7.17?

I understand that we shouldn't remove the `upgrade.php` file, but just curious on the rest of these files.

Thanks, and this is probably a dumb question, but just felt the need to ask anyways.  Usually I remove these files when I install software on websites, but not sure how Drupal uses and/or misuses these files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the document “[Finalize the upgrade](https://drupal.org/upgrade/finished)” (which applies to both upgrades and installations) from the Drupal handbook:

```
The last step in an upgrade is to delete or move the following files from your site:

install.php
CHANGELOG.txt
INSTALL.txt
INSTALL.mysql.txt
INSTALL.pgsql.txt
INSTALL.sqlite.txt
LICENSE.txt
MAINTAINERS.txt
UPGRADE.txt
```

Just to make that clear: the only PHP file to delete is "install.php" (i.e. be sure to leave "upgrade.php" and all other PHP files). And when you delete the TXT files, be sure to keep "robots.txt" since it is used by search engines.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that information!  I was thinking that this is the case, but wasn't sure if these files were used for other purposes...  Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't delete any files. If you really wanted to, you could delete various txt files. A better solution if you are afraid of security is to not let the files be accessed through the web server. Drupal only use the index.php file for serving content.

Comment: Currently these files have the following permission set on them:  0644, is that good enough to not let these files be accessed?

Answer (score 0):

I would love to hear an update and more recent thoughts on this question, and here is why.....

I was just working with a newly updated Drupal site to **Drupal 8.9.20** running the Open Social distribution as a logged-in user with no admin privileges. This is my **ACTIVE PRODUCTION** site!

I deleted a node (News Article) I was trying to embed from a website that refuses to connect on some of their metadata ie: image #1, and after submitting on the delete link, the browser switched to install.php, which as you know sites in the document root.

I was of course shocked to see this and after considering the even innocent response a user might get that lead them to reinstall **THEIR App**, this could be very dangerous, of course.

So, since the last reply on this references Drupal versions from 2014, I was
just wondering your thoughts in this day and age on what are the latest recommendations!

Thanks